# KLogger Permission denied trying to create log file

Tags: apache, permission-denied

I have KLogger installed in my web app and everything worked fine on my XAMPP dev server but once I uploaded all my files to my host I get:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  fopen(/var/log/log_2013-08-15.txt) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/home/user/public_html/site.net/include/KLogger.php</b> on line <b>177</b><br />
```

So far I have tried setting the permissions to 777 on both the var and log folders but this doesn't help.

Please help me trouble shoot this.

My hosting provider provides CPanel.

Comment: This was my error all the way. In all of my other files I have a couple of defines for the file paths and I didn't add them to my klogger initialization so it was trying to create a text file on the root var/log directory instead of my home directory.

Comment: Please post an answer then, instead of a comment, so that this question can be closed out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested I'm answering my own question.

This was my error all the way. In all of my other files I have a couple of defines for the file paths and I didn't add them to my klogger initialization so it was trying to create a text file on the root var/log directory instead of my home directory.